# `mix edeliver build release` push outdated code to build server when running in GitLab CI runner

Tags: git, elixir, gitlab-ci, edeliver, distillery

I am trying to configure my GitLab CI to automatically build my Elixir app and create new release each time when it succeed on `master` branch. However whenever it comes to deployment it fails due to an old Git repository on build server.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration:

```
image: 'elixir:1.3.3'
services:
  - postgres

# …

staging:
  stage: deploy
  environment: staging
  tags:
    - elixir
  before_script:
    - mix local.hex --force
    - mix do deps.get, compile
    - 'which ssh-agent || (apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y)'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_DEPLOY_STAGING_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  script:
    - mix edeliver build release --revision=$CI_BUILD_REF --auto-version=git-revision
    - mix edeliver deploy to staging
  only:
    - master
  cache:
    paths:
      - _build/
      - deps/
```

And output of `edeliver` on CI (app builder is Distillery):

```
$ which ssh-agent || (apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y)
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 373
$ echo "$SSH_DEPLOY_STAGING_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
Identity added: (stdin) (hauleth@niuniobook)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ mix edeliver build release --revision=$CI_BUILD_REF --auto-version=git-revision
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

BUILDING RELEASE OF ONEMEDICAL APP ON BUILD HOST

-----> Authorizing hosts
-----> Ensuring hosts are ready to accept git pushes
-----> Pushing new commits with git to: app@build.server
-----> Resetting remote hosts to 3faf1d077f95ce7207cac7d14dd25b33d648d710
fatal: Could not parse object '3faf1d077f95ce7207cac7d14dd25b33d648d710'.

A remote command failed on:

  app@build.server

Output of the command is shown above and the command executed
on that host is printed below for debugging purposes:

FAILED with exit status 128:

    set -e
    cd /tmp/edeliver/app/builds
    git reset --hard 3faf1d077f95ce7207cac7d14dd25b33d648d710



ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Locally when I run `mix edeliver build` everything works smoothly but I cannot find why when running via CI this fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is how GitLab CI is fetching repositories to test environment. By default it uses `git fetch` strategy which fetches changes, but do not move branches. There are different solutions to that issue but what I have used is to forcefully set `master` to current commit by:

```
git branch -f master HEAD
```

Before executing `mix edeliver`. Alternatively you could use `git pull` to reset to exact branch name instead of `master`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue too; I had to use `branch=` instead of a ref